# Java Hashmap Iterating getting KeySet

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, maps, key

So in my Java program I loop through my entire Hashmap when the program is about to close, getting both the key and value to store into a file.

I would like to know how to get the key, currently it loops through the Hashmap and only gets the value.

The code in question:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> timers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();       
for(int times : timers.values()){
       int playerTime = times;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    for (Entry<String, Integer> e : timers.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        Integer value = e.getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use entry set to retrieve the entries and iterate over the entryset.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet()

Answer (score 0):

You could use [entrySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) method to get each and every entry holding key and value and can iterate over the set as below:

```
 Map<String, Integer> timers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to iterate just over keys, you could use [keySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) method (just like you iterating over values) and iterate over the keys of a hashmap like:

```
 Map<String, Integer> timers = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(map.get(key));//will print value associated with key
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, so would this code work? Pretty much just looping through the entire HashMap, and removing 1 to every key's value, checking if it's 0 and if it is removing the player. Here's the code. http://pastie.org/9858428. Sorry that I didn't put it here, couldn't make it format correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest streaming the `entrySet`:

```
timers.entrySet().stream()
  .forEach(entry -> storeTimer(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```